# error after updating spark to 2.4 version

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I recently updated my Spark version from 2.2 to 2.4.0

I started having an error in this block (which was working fine with 2.2 version):

```
object Crud_mod {

  def f(df: DataFrame,
               options: JDBCOptions,
               conditions: List[String]) {
    val url = options.url
    val tables = options.table
    val dialect = JdbcDialects_mod.get(url)

error: value table is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions
[ERROR]     val tables = options.table
```

So I took a look inside [Spark sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b302caf4d28752a2bf5537c69fd9cbdc8b703e8b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCOptions.scala#L37) and value `table` seems to exist in `JDBCOptions` class.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sources link is pointing to a constructor, that accepts `table` as an argument, but I can't find `table` value in class itself.
However, there's `tableOrQuery` ([here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b302caf4d28752a2bf5537c69fd9cbdc8b703e8b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCOptions.scala#L71)) method, that can be used for your needs, I think.